# Loading your own text dataset to scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to try out a few algorithms in by loading my own dataset. I'm specifically interested in loading  text files (very similar to the 20 NewsGroups dataset http://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/index.html#general-dataset-api). Is there any documentation that explains the format (and the procedure) for loading in data other than the sample datasets?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TfidfVectorizer and others text vectorizers classes in scikit-learn just take a list of Python unicode strings as input. You can thus load the text the way you want depending on the source: database query using SQLAlchemy, json stream from an HTTP API, a CSV file or random text files in folders.

For the last option, if the class information is stored in the folder names holding the text files you can use the [load_files](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_files.html) utility function.