# How to load our own text data to scikit for MeanShift clustering?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am planning to load my own set of unstructured textual data, which can be seen as follows:

```
64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:16:05:49 -0800] "GET /twiki/bin/edit/Main/Double_bounce_sender?topicparent=Main.ConfigurationVariables HTTP/1.1" 401 12846
```

Or it can also take the following form:

```
/usr/local/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf: line 68: Error: Blank line following agentaddress token.
NET-SNMP version 5.3.1
```

Basically, the program does not care about the structure of the given data.

I have edited the code given in the MeanShift example in scikit, so that my code loads my own set of data. The input file is named as **input** in this case.

```
for idx, line in enumerate(input):
   if(len(line) == ''):
       continue;
   line = line.strip()
   tmpNumPy = np.array([line])
   print tmpNumPy
   example = np.append(example, tmpNumPy)

# Compute clustering with MeanShift

# The following bandwidth can be automatically detected using
bandwidth = estimate_bandwidth(example, quantile=0.2, n_samples=500)

ms = MeanShift(bandwidth=bandwidth, bin_seeding=True)
ms.fit(X)
labels = ms.labels_
cluster_centers = ms.cluster_centers_

labels_unique = np.unique(labels)
n_clusters_ = len(labels_unique)

print(labels_unique)
print("number of estimated clusters : %d" % n_clusters_)
```

However, when I run this code it gives me the following error:

```
ValueError: data type not understood
```

I would like to know how to load a set of textual data rather than numeric values in to the MeanShift clustering using scikit, or are there any other approaches which I can take?

*Note: I have already gone through the following links without any luck:*

[Meanshift in scikit learn (python) doesn't understand datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030227/meanshift-in-scikit-learn-python-doesnt-understand-datatype)

[Loading your own text dataset to scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050660/loading-your-own-text-dataset-to-scikit-learn)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would like to form clusters of text, first you need to represent your set of textual data in a vector space. The standard way to do this is called [Latent Semantic Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_semantic_analysis)  (LSA). The basic gist is that you calculate a matrix where each row represents a document and each column represents a term. The elements of the matrix are the term frequency–inverse document frequency (tfidf) values for each term in each document. This matrix will be huge and sparse. You'll use singular value decomposition (SVD) to reduce the dimensionality of this matrix to a number of "topics" that you choose. The standard is number of topics is 200-500.

An excellent Python package for LSA is called [Gensim](http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/).

Once you've represented your text as vectors, you can cluster them based on the cosine distance between them, which represents how semantically similar any two documents are. The sklearn MeanShift implementation doesn't let you specify cosine distance, but you can still get a good measure of semantic similarity if you normalize the vectors before clustering.